# Emacs from activities overview behaving differently than emacs from terminal - how to find our what command is run

Tags: gnome-terminal, emacs, activities-overview

DISCLAIMER: With "activities overview" I mean whatever is invoked when pressing the Super key / Windows key.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 and depending how I start emacs (v27.1, installed using `apt`), [julia-repl](https://github.com/tpapp/julia-repl/) either works or does not:

`julia-repl` works when I start emacs as follows:

- typing `emacs` or `/usr/bin/emacs` or `gtk-launch emacs` in the terminal (starts emacs in a GUI)
- typing `emacs -nw` or `/usr/bin/emacs -nw` or `gtk-launch emacs-term` in the terminal (starts emacs inside the terminal)

`julia-repl` fails when I start emacs as follows:

- clicking the `Emacs (GUI)` icon in the activities overview (starts emacs in a GUI)
- clicking the `Emacs (Terminal)` icon in the activities overview (starts emacs in a terminal)

Does anybody know what can cause the divergence in behaviour? Here's the content of my `/usr/share/applications/emacs.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Emacs (GUI)
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=GNU Emacs is an extensible, customizable text editor - and more
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
TryExec=/usr/bin/emacs
Exec=/usr/bin/emacs %F
Icon=emacs
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;Development;TextEditor;
StartupWMClass=Emacs
Keywords=Text;Editor;
```

And here's a minimal `init.el` for which the error occurs:

```
require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")))
(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents (package-refresh-contents))
(require 'use-package)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)

(require 'julia-mode)

(add-to-list 'load-path "path-of-julia-binary")
(require 'julia-repl)
(add-hook 'julia-mode-hook 'julia-repl-mode) ;; always use minor mode
```

Comment: Strange. `gtk-launch emacs`, which works well for you, is equivalent to clicking the launcher in the overview, which does not work for you. That command launches `emacs.desktop`. Are there different versions of `emacs.desktop` in different places on your system?

Comment: No, the only `emacs.desktop` file on my system is `/usr/share/applications/emacs.desktop`. Is there a way to get more detailed debug information on what goes wrong when I try to start `julia-repl`? What is written in the messages and warnings buffer is pretty generic and nondescript.